# fix unity launcher loading error

Tags: unity-game-engine

i m totally new to unity and getting such issue on working with vuforia  packages in unity 
getting launcher error kindly help me identify and fix this error

Error loading launcher://unity/C:/Users/Smuggler/AppData/Roaming/Unity/Packages/node_modules/unity-editor-home/dist/index.html?code=xkQ-CJ4YSJUr37csNoaguw00ff&locale=en&session_state=11869da0673b479ab25dfd5fb663cc2fe82b4fee4ce41fd8d28a8fd85e3dbf42.jYhCitBiBK23dZSCSMrpRQ00ff#/login

Answer (score 0):

oh i simply just reinstalled the older version 
and it fixed up my problem
v 5.01

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem using the 2017.1 version. Should be fixed in 2017.2

https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-loading-launcher.486127/